# Is it possible that a decision node has only one outgoing flow?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am working on an activity diagram for a web application.
And now there is a need for a decision to press a button.
But you can only press the button if you pressed another button before. But you don't have to push it.
So my question is must a decision node has always two or more outgoing flows or is it possible to say that this decision has only one outgoing flow?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, whether something happens if the user does not push the button.

If nothing happens, then I would model the step as an activity not as a decision. If he has to press the button to continue, then it is the normal flow of the program and should be modeled as such.